# How to display conversation list in php pdo displaying last message on each conversations sent and received even if the other user has not replied yet

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, message

I've been trying to get a query that would help me to display conversation list like any chat web app, I want to mix the sent messages(I mean conversations) with received messages even if the other user has not replied it. and only show the last conversation made.

I am using PHP here is the query I tried.
I Have a message table and users table
[above message table, below user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kghqz.jpg)

```
public function conversations($user_id){$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `messages` LEFT JOIN users ON `messageFrom` = :user_id OR `messageTo` = :user_id AND `messageID` IN (SELECT max(`messageID`) FROM `messages` WHERE `messageFrom` = :user_id OR `messageTo` = :user_id) WHERE `messageTo` = :user_id and `messageFrom` = user_id or `messageFrom` = :user_id and `messageTo` = `user_id` GROUP BY messageTo, messageFrom ORDER BY `messageID` DESC ");
$stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

Comment: Please add you table as text and read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: are you only want to print the last one message.

Comment: please mention all the code where you are printing the messages